# Change anything in controller and routing error occurs, but can recover after restarting server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I have this strange error.Everything works fine when I start the server.

I browse `http://lvh.me:3000/admin/topics` and it displays properly

Then when I change *anything* in *any* controller (even just adding blank lines), the rails will say:

```
Routing Error
uninitialized constant Admin::TopicsController::Topic
```

and I refresh it, it will display:

```
NoMethodError in Admin/topics#index
Showing /Users/john/Code/v2/app/views/admin/topics/index.html.erb where line #12 raised:
undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
```

Then when I restart the server, everything is normal again. If I change anything in controller then it will happen again.

It only happens under this url.

My routes are:

```
  namespace :admin do
    resources :topics do
      resources :comments, :controller => "topic/comments"
    end
    resources :attachments
  end
```

The relevant controllers are:

```
app/controllers/admin/topics_controller.rb
app/controllers/admin/topic/comments_controller.rb
```

It is really strange that it works properly in the first time, but then breaks if controller is changed (even when adding blank lines). Could it be that comments controller is under the topic folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the folder name from `topic` to `topics` and the problem disappeared. Not sure why but it is probably convention pushed to the edge.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're running afoul of the Rails convention that a non-gem class `X::Y::Z` should be found at a path that ends with `x/y/z.rb`, and vice versa. You should probably just name that controller `TopicCommentsController` and put it into `app/controllers/admin/topic_comments_controller.rb`.